# How To Charge Android Phone In Fastboot (Bootloader) Mode?

Tags: battery, fastboot, charging, bootloader

My Android Phone Is Not Charging. Bootloader Shows The Warning Battery Low. I Accedentaly Erased /Boot /Recovery /System Partition. And Because Battery Is Low I Can Not Flash Boot.Img And Recovery.Img.
Is This Happening Because I Erased /Boot /Recovery If Yes Then Why ? When I Connect The Phone With My Laptop On Fastboot Mode It Starts The Charging [AND THAT TO VERY SLOW ] Not In Wall Charger.

I Did Not Find Any Working Solution On Xda , Stackoverflow Etc. Can Anybody Help Me To Solving This Plz.

Comment: What happens if you shut down the phone and then connect it to the charger?

Comment: Firstly It Does Not Shutdown , When I Hold Power Button To Switch Off The Phone Nothing Happens.When The Battery Gets Discharge Fully Then It Switch Off.
And Then I Plug It With Charger It Starts Charging Only For 2-3 Min (The Chargin Notification Light Turns On ) And Then It Starts Up Automatically And Go Into Bootloader  And It Stops Charging.(Charging Notification Light Turs Off )
Bootloader Gives Warning Battery Is Low.

Comment: If Some How My Phone Dont Start After Pluging  Charger Then I Guess It Can Charge.
I Dont Know I Think Bootloader  Is Stoping My Phone From Charing.

Comment: for flashing in preloader or edl mode, no battery is needed at all